# ELK most appropriate timestamp name _ or @

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

What is the most appropriate name for the timestamp when utilizing Logstash to parse logs into Elasticsearch, then visualizing with Kibana?

I am defining the timestamp using date in a filter:

```
date {
     match => [ "logtime", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

Logstash automatically puts this into the `@timestamp` field. Kibana can be configured to use any correctly formatted field as the timestamp, but it seems to be correct to use `_timestamp` in Elasticsearch. To do that, you have to mutate and rename the datestamp field.

```
mutate {
     rename => { "@timestamp" => "_timestamp" }
}
```

Which is *slightly* annoying.

This question could be entirely semantic - but is it most correct to use `_timestamp`, or is it just fine to use `@timestamp`? Are there any other considerations which should influence the naming of the timestamp field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticsearch allows you to define fields starting with an underscore, however, Kibana (since v4) will only show the ones declared outside of the `_source` document.

You should definitely keep with `@timestamp` which is the standard way to name the timestamp field in Logstash. Kibana will not allow you to use `_timestamp`.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `_timestamp` is reserved and [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) special field name. Actually any field names starting with underscore are [reserved](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2551) for elasticsearch future internal usage. AFAIK logstash documentation [examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html) use `@timestamp` as field name
 without any renaming.